Acceder a datos fuera de la clase
Tengo este archivo donde accedo a datos provenientes de una db y del front, lo que quiero es dentro de la clase, acceder al valor de la variable $monto = $compra->total; declarada en las primeras lineas, pero no logro hacerlo, al acceder al valor recibo null, pero al hacer var_dump(), el valor si esta, si llega y si existe
echo '<pre>';
  ($compra);
echo '</pre>';

luego cuando intento acceder dentro de la clase en la function y llamar a $this->monto pero aca es donde me llega como null...
alguna suferencia para poder acceder al dato.
<?php
    include('configuracion.php');
?>

<?php

include('vendor/autoload.php');

$id_compra_encriptado = isset($_GET['id_compra']) ? $_GET['id_compra'] : NULL;
$id_compra = funcion::desencriptar($id_compra_encriptado);

$compra = $db->row('compras', '*', "id='{$id_compra}'");

$id_compra = $compra->id;
$email_cliente = $compra->email;

$monto = $compra->total;
/* echo '<pre>';
($compra);
echo '</pre>'; */

//Creamos la instancia de la clase, enviando los parametros que el __contructor pide  $db y $monto
$cuotealosender = new CuotealoSender($monto);
$cuotealosender->buildJsonRequestWithProducts();

?>

<?php

class CuotealoSender
{
    private $rsa;
    private $cuotealoPublicKeyFileName = 'cuotealo_pe/public_bcp.txt';
    private $publicKey = '';
    public  $db; // Agrega una propiedad para la conexión de la base de datos
    public  $monto;

    function __construct($db, $monto)
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->cuotealoPublicKeyFileName) || !is_readable($this->cuotealoPublicKeyFileName)) {
            throw new \Exception('Public key file does not exist or is not readable.');
        }
        $this->publicKey = file_get_contents($this->cuotealoPublicKeyFileName);
        $this->rsa = phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader::load($this->publicKey)->withHash('sha256')->withMGFHash('sha1');
        $this->db = $db; // Almacena la conexión de la base de datos en la propiedad $db
        $this->monto = $monto; // Almacena el valor de monto en la propiedad $monto
        var_dump($this->monto, 'Valor');
    }

    function encryptValue($value)
    {
        return base64_encode($this->rsa->encrypt($value));
    }

    function buildJsonRequestWithProducts()
    {
        $cuotealo_moneda = 'PEN';

        $productDetais[] = array('name' => 'Nike', 'quantity' => 1, 'amount' => 120);
        $productDetais[] = array('name' => 'Reebok', 'quantity' => 2, 'amount' => 150);
        $billingInformation = array(
            'firstName' => 'Nombre',
            'lastName' => 'Apellido',
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'telephone' => '12312345678',
            'street' => 'calle falsa 123',
            'city' => '',
            'region' => 'ARE',
            'countryId' => 'PE',
        );

        $cuotealoRequest = array(
           
            'totalAmount' => $this->encryptValue($this->monto),
            'currency' => $this->encryptValue('PEN'),
           
            
            'hasDetail' => true,
            'subTotal' => $this->monto,
            'discount' => 0,
            'shippingCost' => 0,
            'productDetails' => $productDetais,
            'billingInformation' => $billingInformation,
        );

        /* echo '<pre>';
            //var_dump($cuotealosender->buildJsonRequestWithProducts());
            var_dump($cuotealoRequest);
        echo '</pre>'; */

        return json_encode($cuotealoRequest);
    }

    function buildJsonRequest()
    {
        //$monto = $this->monto;

        $cuotealoRequest = array(
           
            'totalAmount' => $this->encryptValue($this->monto),
            'currency' => $this->encryptValue('PEN'),
            'redirectPath' => 'https://ecommerce.com/checkout?id=123',
            'backUrl' => 'https://ecommerce.com/back',
           
            'merchantName' => $this->encryptValue('Ecommerce 1'), //Solo para pasarelas de pago
            'merchantLogo' => $this->encryptValue('https://ecommerce.com/public/logo.jpg'),
            'hasDetail' => false,
            'subTotal' => 0,
            'discount' => 0,
            'shippingCost' => 0,
        );

        return json_encode($cuotealoRequest);
    }
}

?>

Esto es lo que me llega en el objeto.
object(stdClass)#178 (159) {
  ["total"]=>
    string(6) "115.00"
}


¿puedes hacer un ´var_dump($compra)´ para ver la estructura del  objeto?

si, si lo hice, si los valores llegan todos!

@WAlemanhe actualizado el post y deje el codigo de como viene el valor en el objeto!

en principio tendrías que definir $this->monto en la class, como private si la vas usar por "dentro" o como public si la vas a usar por "fuera"

@aloMalbarez Estaba escribiendo eso mismo!

btw php7 permite meter cosa sin definir previamente en las class y por lo general pasan esas cosas

Primero :  En el constructor de la clase CuotealoSender estas utilizando el atributo monto  que no esta definido  como tal.
Debes definirlo de la siguiente manera
class CuotealoSender
{
    private $rsa;
    private $cuotealoPublicKeyFileName = 'cuotealo_pe/public_bcp.txt';
    private $publicKey = '';
    public  $db; 
    private $monto;  //  <------------ Aqui
    
    

Segundo : para utilizar las propiedades y métodos de una clase debes crear una instancia   de la misma  (o definir los métodos estáticos)
<?php
  include('configuracion.php');
  include('vendor/autoload.php');

  $id_compra_encriptado = isset($_GET['id_compra']) ? $_GET['id_compra'] : NULL;
  $id_compra = funcion::desencriptar($id_compra_encriptado);
  $compra = $db->row('compras', '*', "id='{$id_compra}'");

  $id_compra = $compra->id;
  $email_cliente = $compra->email;

  //Creamos la instancia de la clase, enviando los parametros que el __contructor pide  $db y $monto
  $cuotealosender = new CuotealoSender($db,$compra->total);
  $cuotealosender->buildJsonRequestWithProducts();

  var_dump($cuotealosender->buildJsonRequestWithProducts();
  );

?>

Tercero deja la funcion buildJsonRequestWithProducts() como estaba.
   function buildJsonRequestWithProducts()
    {

        $productDetais[] = array('name' => 'Nike', 'quantity' => 1, 'amount' => 120);
        $billingInformation = array(
            'firstName' => 'Nombre',
            'lastName' => 'Apellido',
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'telephone' => '12312345678',
            'street' => 'calle falsa 123',
            'city' => '',
            'region' => 'ARE',
            'countryId' => 'PE',
        );

        $cuotealoRequest = array(
            'ecommerceId' => '',
            'operationId' => ,
            'totalAmount' => $this->encryptValue($this->monto),  //<---- ESTA LINEA ES IMPORTANTE
            'currency' => $this->encryptValue('PEN'),
            'redirectPath' => '', 
            'backUrl' => '', //url de cancelacion
            'merchantLogo' => ,
            'hasDetail' => true,
            'subTotal' => $montofinal,
            'discount' => 0,
            'shippingCost' => 0,
            'productDetails' => $productDetais,
            'billingInformation' => $billingInformation,
        );

        return json_encode($cuotealoRequest);
    }

Por ultimo : para utilizar el metodo encryptValue($monto)   lo debes hacer de la siguiente manera
var_dump($cuotealosender->encryptValue($compra->total));

Como Nota:
$this es una referencia al objeto invocador (usualmente el objeto al cual pertenece el método,  en resumen solo puedes usarlo dentro de la clase
Un saludo  y sigue programando. =)

muchas gracias, he probado el codigo pero no me funciona, por tanto ya he compartido el codigo del archivo completo, a ver si se me pasa algo mas!
